# How can I create full Moderation comment system using wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, comments, dokan

In Basic WordPress comment moderation - "Admin Moderation only for the first comment, no moderation option for reply message". Hear what I am looking is "Comment moderation for each comments and its reply like first comment, first reply, second reply and so on. All messages are must verified by website admin".

My website is a multi vendor website, sharing contact details (customer and seller) are prohibited. I am using wordpress comment section for Product Enquiry system.

Product Enquiry with admin moderation are not in market.

Guide me to start to create the plugin or any plugin in market. Please share the link.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Their is no plugin for above requirement. So I am moving into development also looking for developer.